# Create a link that can later be customized to different URL

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

I would like to create a link that I can customize later.

For example,

I create a href link in the footer of the website I developed for my client with the URL that forwards to my current Web design website.

In the future, if I have to change my Web design website URL I will just customize that footer link forward destination to another one without having to access the CPanel of my client's website.

Please tell me how is it possible to do. Is this possible to with any link shortener services?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to set up a redirect from your old site to your new, with a `301` status code.  This is easily done with a simple configuration directive in your web server config.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt if there is any link generator service that let you change the redirection link after generated.

If you will be able to access your previous url, link it with redirection page that will redirect client into your current url.

Or get a free domain that only works as redirection link.

Comment: Plenty of the link generation services do offer APIs.  That's not the best thing to do in this case though.